# Asp.net code not performing on actual server as localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that works fine on my localhost using IIS7 but when i upload it to my server it is behaving not the same as it did on my localhost
 For example the submit button when clicked should check validation which it does on my localhost and then redirects to a URL if the validation is correct

But when the same is tried on the actual server over here
[The not working link](http://www.singaporetelugusamajam.org/entercontact.aspx)

the problem started when i introduced a redirect url (in C# code is Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");)  in to the c# code...if there is a better way to do this all this hassle wont be necessary..tks

this is the code that i used

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>

<script runat="server">


protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAddress.Text = "";
    string xmlPath = MapPath("Books.xml");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    //Check if the file already exists or not
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath))
    {
        doc.Load(xmlPath);
        XmlNode bookNode = CreateBookNode(doc);
        //Get reference to the book node and append the book node to it
        XmlNode bookStoreNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("bookstore");
        bookStoreNode.AppendChild(bookNode);
        lblResult.Text = "XML Document has been successfully updated";
        txtAddress.Text = ""; Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
    else
    {            
        XmlNode declarationNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "", "");
        doc.AppendChild(declarationNode);
        XmlNode comment = doc.CreateComment("This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database");
        doc.AppendChild(comment);            
        XmlNode bookstoreNode = doc.CreateElement("bookstore");
        XmlNode bookNode = CreateBookNode(doc);                        
        //Append the book node to the bookstore node            
        bookstoreNode.AppendChild(bookNode);
        //Append the bookstore node to the document
        doc.AppendChild(bookstoreNode);
        lblResult.Text = "XML Document has been successfully created";
        txtAddress.Text = "";Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
    doc.Save(xmlPath);



}

XmlNode CreateBookNode(XmlDocument doc)
{

    /* 
     XmlNode bookNode = doc.CreateElement("book");
     //Add the genre attribute to the book node
     XmlAttribute genreAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("genre");
     genreAttribute.Value = txtGenre.Text;        
     bookNode.Attributes.Append(genreAttribute);

     http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/XML/SaveformdatatoXMLfile.htm

     */


    XmlNode bookNode = doc.CreateElement("book");

    //Declaration of the Main Node (Particulars)
    XmlNode particularsnode = doc.CreateElement("Particulars");
    //Declaration of Child Nodes in the Main Node(Particulars)
    XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
    XmlNode phoneNode = doc.CreateElement("Phone");
    XmlNode emailNode = doc.CreateElement("Email");
    XmlNode AddressNode = doc.CreateElement("Address");
    //Getting the textvalue from the htmlform
    nameNode.InnerText = txtName.Text;
    phoneNode.InnerText = txtPhone.Text;
    emailNode.InnerText = txtEmail.Text;
    AddressNode.InnerText = txtAddress.Text;
    //Updating the XML file here the particularsnode has various children and they are being updated
    particularsnode.AppendChild(nameNode);
    particularsnode.AppendChild(phoneNode);
    particularsnode.AppendChild(emailNode);
    particularsnode.AppendChild(AddressNode);
    bookNode.AppendChild(particularsnode);


    //Declaration of the Main Node (BookParticulars)
    XmlNode bookparticularsnode = doc.CreateElement("BookParticulars");
    //Declaration of Child Nodes in the Main Node(BookParticulars)
    XmlNode schoolNode = doc.CreateElement("School");
    XmlNode currentlevelNode = doc.CreateElement("CurrentLevel");
    XmlNode GABDNode = doc.CreateElement("GiveAwayBookDetails");
    XmlNode LRNode = doc.CreateElement("LevelRequired");
    //Getting the textvalue from the htmlform
    schoolNode.InnerText = txtSchool.Text;
    currentlevelNode.InnerText = txtCurrentLevel.Text;
    GABDNode.InnerText = txtGABD.Text;
    LRNode.InnerText = txtLR.Text;
    //Updating the XML file here the particularsnode has various children and they are being updated
    particularsnode.AppendChild(schoolNode);
    particularsnode.AppendChild(currentlevelNode);
    particularsnode.AppendChild(GABDNode);
    particularsnode.AppendChild(LRNode);
    bookNode.AppendChild(bookparticularsnode);



    return bookNode;
}
public static string NewLineToBreak(string input)
{
    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"[\n|\r]+");
    return regEx.Replace(input, "<br />");
}

protected void txtAddress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAddress.Text = "Woodlands Drive 14\n Blk";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you validating the fields, are you doing it on the client side?

Comment: @user788312 no at server side as well

Comment: So you're validating server-side? Is `if (System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath))` falling into the else condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Server.MapPath` as describes in [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) or try using `Page.ResolveUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using fully qualified paths for the resources you're trying to load?

e.g.:

```
string xmlPath = MapPath("~/Books.xml");
```

-or-

```
string xmlPath = MapPath("~/<some_sub_dir>/Books.xml");
```

Also, is your production server throwing exceptions?  If so, displaying them locally only and using a local http session to see them might help.

example web.config section for customerrors:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested still no use, actually i have tried this with out the "~/Books.xml" and it was working fine the problem started when i introduced a redirect url in to the c# code if there is a better way to do this all this hassle wont be necessary..tks

Comment: Could you please try commenting Response.Redirect statement from your code.

Comment: I noticed that the books.xml file is not being created in the firstplace sory about that previously it was in my ie cache

Comment: @user788312 ok tried that and it is working fine, but how do i redirect it to a new page once the submit button is clicked and it should perform all the necessary checks as well..tks so helpful

Comment: maybe try Server.Transfer() instead of Response.Redirect()?  Response.Redirect() could break if there's external proxy stuff going on.

Comment: You create an integer variable count with initial value as 0 and if an error is found in your code, increment  it by 1 each time and in the end check if the count is 0, if it is call your redirect method, else show the error as Label or which ever way you want.

Comment: @user788312 possible to give me some code as i am having difficulty to place ur suggested solution tks

Comment: @ebyrob but i want my page to redirect to books.xml after the guy enters the details and passes the validation..tks btw i tried server.redirect and it is giving me errors this is how i  type it in the code Server.Transfer("~/books.xml",true);  tried with out the true as well but not creating books.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the fully qualified path and see if its picking the XML file. I am sure it might be some path issue that is causing the exception. Also make sure you turn on the Custom Errors mode so that you can see the error.

Comment: You create an integer variable count with initial value as 0 and if an error is found in your code, increment it by 1 each time and in the end check if the count is 0, if it is call your redirect method, else show the error as Label or which ever way you want.